# Populate calendar list from start and end timestamps in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, timestamp, excel-2010

I have a list of activities with start timestamps and end timestamps, and I need to populate a list of dates with corresponding activities and durations.

I have tried various convoluted IF statements, VLOOKUPS and INDEX MATCH.

I have data as follows:

```
Activity Name   Location          Start                  End          
--------------- ---------- --------------------- --------------------- 
Act1            Loc1       13/07/2019 12:00 AM   15/07/2019 12:00 PM  
Act2            Loc1       20/07/2019 12:00 AM   22/07/2019 12:00 PM  
Act3            Loc2       11/07/2019 12:00 AM   13/07/2019 12:00 PM
```

and want to display it as follows:

```
 Date         Loc1_Activities   Hours   Loc2_Activities   Hours  
------------ ----------------- ------- ----------------- ------- 
1/07/2019                                                       
2/07/2019                                                       
3/07/2019                                                       
4/07/2019                                                       
5/07/2019                                                       
6/07/2019                                                       
7/07/2019                                                       
8/07/2019                                                       
9/07/2019                                                       
10/07/2019                                                      
11/07/2019                             Act3                 24  
12/07/2019                             Act3                 24  
13/07/2019   Act1                 24   Act3                 12  
14/07/2019   Act1                 24                            
15/07/2019   Act1                 12                            
16/07/2019                                                      
17/07/2019                                                      
18/07/2019                                                      
19/07/2019                                                      
20/07/2019   Act2                 24                            
21/07/2019   Act2                 24                            
22/07/2019   Act2                 12                            
23/07/2019                                                      
24/07/2019                                                      
25/07/2019                                                      
26/07/2019                                                      
27/07/2019                                                      
28/07/2019                                                      
29/07/2019                                                      
30/07/2019                                                      
31/07/2019
```

Comment: Show what you did with vlookup, index & match... maybe just a correction would help.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd want to do this in Power Query. However, this question has an `excel-2010` tag and I think Power Query is only available as an external add-in in Excel 2010 (at least for Windows).

Second easiest approach might be with VBA. But this question has no `vba` tag. So presume you want to achieve this with formulas only.

This is the layout of my worksheet named `"Sheet1"`, which I think matches your first table.

[image: Source data]

This is the layout of my output worksheet (where I'm using formulas to re-structure the data). I think it matches your second table.

[image: Output data]

---

• Formula in yellow cell (`B1`) is:

```
="Loc"&QUOTIENT(COLUMN()-COLUMN($B$1),2)+1
```

*Can be dragged to the right as far as you need it to go.*

---

• Array formula in green cell (`B4`) is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4,AGGREGATE(15,6,IF(($A4>=INT(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$4))*($A4<ROUNDUP(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$4,0))*(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4=B$1),ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4)-ROW(Sheet1!$A$2)+1,NA()),1)),"")
```

*This must be entered using `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` (Excel will automatically put curly braces `{}` around your formula to let you know it's an array formula). Drag it down to fill the cells below.*

---

• Array formula in blue cell (`C4`) is:

```
=IF(LEN(B4),(MIN($A4+1,INDEX(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$4,AGGREGATE(15,6,IF(($A4>=INT(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$4))*($A4<ROUNDUP(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$4,0))*(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4=B$1),ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4)-ROW(Sheet1!$A$2)+1,NA()),1)))-MAX($A4,INDEX(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$4,AGGREGATE(15,6,IF(($A4>=INT(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$4))*($A4<ROUNDUP(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$4,0))*(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4=B$1),ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4)-ROW(Sheet1!$A$2)+1,NA()),1))))*24,"")
```

*This must be entered using `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` (Excel will automatically put curly braces `{}` around your formula to let you know it's an array formula). Drag it down to fill the cells below.*

---

• You can either enter a date in cell `A4` or you can this formula (and drag it down to cells below):

```
=DATE(2019,7,1)+ROW()-ROW($A$4)
```

---

*When you drag the array formulas (green and blue cells) to the right, you'll need to ensure you don't overwrite an `*_Hours` column's formula with an `*_Activities` column's formula. If you drag them as a unit (both cells or columns) selected, Excel will automatically take care of this for you. Hope that makes sense.*

---

Formulas for titles (though not necessary for the above to work):

- In cell `B3`: `=B$1&"_Activities"`
- In cell `C3`: `=C$1&"_Hours"`

*Then drag across (as a unit) to the right.*